Definition of internal energy $U$
We can define the internal energy as the average of the energies weighted by their probability of occurrence (partition function). This would only depend on the temperature ($T$) and not on the number of moles ($n$) and would refer to the average energy per particle. However we can also define it as the following: $U=\frac{3}{2}nRT$.
Obviously this depends on the number of moles ($n$) and refers to the energy of the system as a whole. So which definition is correct or are they equivalent (beats me) and how if they depend on different things?
The definitions are confusing me.
EDIT #1
Two systems with the same mean energy could still have vastly different total internal energies if they have a different number of moles.

The one computed from the partition function would also depends on the number of particles... For example, if we only have kinetic energy and N particles, we would have N independent gaussian integral and the average energy would simply be the sum of the average energy of one integral. Thus the total would be the sum of N terms... Perhaps, more clearly: U = $\langle E \rangle = \langle E_1\rangle + \langle E_2 \rangle + \dots + \langle E_N \rangle$ with $E$ the total energy and $E_i$ the energy of particle i.

@Syrocco the probability would depend on $\Omega$ which would depend on $n$ the number of combinations right? Then yeah it would depend on n

@Syrocco would you like to write an answer?

sure. Tell me if it answered your question or not. I'm not so sure what the problem is.

I am not quite sure where the issue is but it looks like you have the impression that the average energy (usually) computed from a statistical ensemble is an average energy BY particle and not the total average energy. Usually, we compute the average total energy.
Also, the average energy (kinetic + potential) is the internal energy.
For example, let's take $H = \sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{p_i^2}{2m}$, the hamiltonian of free particles, I.E an ideal gas! The probability to obtain some microstate with momentum $\{\tilde p_1,\tilde  p_2, \dots, \tilde p_N\}$ is:
$$P(\tilde p_1,\tilde  p_2, \dots, \tilde p_N)=\dfrac{1}{Z}e^{H(p_1 = \tilde p_1,p_2= \tilde  p_2, \dots, p_N =\tilde p_N)/T}=\dfrac{1}{Z}e^{-\dfrac{\tilde p_1^2}{2m T}}e^{-\dfrac{\tilde p_2^2}{2m T}}\dots e^{-\dfrac{\tilde p_N^2}{2m T}}\tag 1$$
and  the average energy is:
$$\langle E\rangle=\langle H \rangle=\dfrac{1}{2m}\sum_{i = 1}^N\left\langle p_i^2\right\rangle \tag 2$$
Each exponential in (1) being independent on the others (meaning that each velocity of each particle is independent on the other), the average value in (2) can simply be rewritten as:
$$\langle E\rangle= \dfrac{1}{2m}\sum_{i = 1}^N\left\langle p_i^2\right\rangle = N e \tag 3$$
with $e=\dfrac{\langle p_i^2\rangle}{2m}=\dfrac{\langle p_{454}^2\rangle}{2m}=\dfrac{\langle p_1^2\rangle}{2m}$, the average energy of 1 particle. Which, in 3D is, from the equipartition theorem $3T/2$ (or from the average computed from (1) and (2)). Hence, you recover the result you gave (since I set $k_B = 1 = R$).

But in the end, I think you got confused between the energy of 1 particle (which is indeed independent on $N$ or $n$ for an extensive system) and the energy of the system, which, due to the extensivity of the system, must be linearly dependent on $N$. This also holds for interacting system but it is more complicated.


This would only depend on the temperature (T)

Internal energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energies at the molecular level. Only kinetic energy is a function of temperature.

However we can also define it as the following: $U=\frac{3}{2}nRT$.

That only applies to an ideal gas where molecular potential energy is considered negligible.

Obviously this depends on the number of moles (n) and refers to the
energy of the system as a whole.

As it should. Internal energy is an extensive property, meaning it depends on the amount of mass.
Hope this helps.

Surely, the mean potential energy will depend on $T$ as seen from the virial for example... Maybe you are not talking about "average" value, then in this case, saying that kinetic energy is a function of temperature is slightly confusing..

@Syrocco the equation doesn’t account for the change in internal energy during a constant temperature phase change
